# Calling a non-static method from a static method

Tags: php, function, oop

I think it is very basic functionality, please help.
How can I call non-static method into static-method in php.

```
class Country {
    public function getCountries() {
        return 'countries';
    }

    public static function countriesDropdown() {
        $this->getCountries();
    }
}
```

Comment: But, why isn't `getCountries` a static method as well, since it doesn't use `$this` at all ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Preferred way..

It is better to make the `getCountries()` method **static** instead.

```
<?php

class Country {
    public static function getCountries() {
        return 'countries';
    }

    public static function countriesDropdown() {
        return self::getCountries();
    }
}
$c = new Country();
echo $c::countriesDropdown(); //"prints" countries
```

---

Adding a `self` keyword displays the *PHP Strict Standards Notice* To **avoid that** you can create an object instance of the very same class and call the method associated with it.

### Calling a non-static method from a static method

```
<?php

class Country {
    public function getCountries() {
        return 'countries';
    }

    public static function countriesDropdown() {
        $c = new Country();
        return $c->getCountries();
    }
}

$c = new Country();
echo $c::countriesDropdown(); //"prints" countries
```

Comment: Yes you are right but there is a warning Strict standards: Non-static method Country::getCountries() should not be called statically

Comment: Sorry I was away.. To avoid that you can create an instance inside the static function of the very same class and do it.

Comment: @zarpio, I was just wondering why not make the `getCountries()` method static instead ? So you don't have go through all these hurdles ;)

Answer (score 1):

You even use `Class Name`

```
public static function countriesDropdown() {
    echo Country::getCountries();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but there is a warning Strict standards: Non-static method Country::getCountries() should not be called statically

Answer (score 1):

You cannot straight forward do that for that you need create a instance of the class & have to call the non-static method,

```
class Country {
    public function getCountries() {
        return 'countries';
    }

    public static function countriesDropdown() {
        $country = new Country();
        return $country->getCountries();
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HdGWIf)**.